# Flask with mongodb return nothing

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I've got a method like :

```
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["test"]

def find_all(cls):

    print (mycol.find())
```

and it's printing all collection like :

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5e1834e77c3b18d7864ad381'), 'test_id': 1, 'test': "test1"}, 
{'_id': ObjectId('5e1834f07c3b18d7864ad382'), 'flash_id': 2,'test': "test2"}, 
{'_id': ObjectId('5e1834f47c3b18d7864ad383'), 'flash_id': 3,'test': "test3"}]
```

but when I changed print to return:

```
def find_all(cls):

    return mycol.find()
```

it returns only :

```
{
    "test": [
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

my testList class looks like :

```
class TestList(Resource):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return {"test": tests_list_schema.dump(TestModel.find_all())}, 200
```

`tests_list_schema = TestsSchema(many=True)`

and

```
ma = Marshmallow() 

class TestsSchema(ma.Schema): 
    class Meta: 
        model = TestsModel
```

Any idea or hint what I'm doing wrong ?

thanks.

Comment: what is `tests_list_schema.dump` for ?

Comment: question has been updated